# Assigning Numerical Values to Hand in Blackjack Game in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can someone please tell me how I can assign numerical values to the cards in a player's hands? I'm stuck at `self.checkvalue`because how I have it currently set up is I'm using string to show both the rank and the suit. I can't seem to figure out how to get the rank of each card in a player's hand and using that to look up the numerical value in the dictionary.

Thanks!

This is what I have so far:

```
import random

rank = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace']
suit = ['Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Hearts', 'Spade']

card_val = {'2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, '10':10, 'Jack':10, 'Queen':10, 'King':10, 'Ace':1}

class Card(object):

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rank) + ' of ' + str(self.suit)

    def grab_suit(self):
        return self.suit

    def grab_rank(self):
        return self.rank

    def draw(self):
        print(self.suit + self.rank)

class Deck(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []    
        for i in rank:
            for j in suit:
                self.cards.append(Card(i,j))

    def __str__(self):
        return str([str(card) for card in self.cards])

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def deal(self):
        single_card = self.cards.pop()
        return single_card

deck = Deck()

class PlayerHand(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = []

    def hit(self):
        self.value.append(deck.deal())
        return self.value

    def __str__(self):
        return str([str(card) for card in self.value])

    def checkvalue(self):
        for card in self.value:
            handvalue += card_val[(self.value)]

hand = PlayerHand()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `isdigit()` to check, and then a simpler check:

```
def getCardVal(card):
  if card.isdigit():
    return int(card)
  elif card == "Ace":
    return 1
  else:
    return 10
```

But I think a dictionary is the best way as it's the most readable and easiest to add values to.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a few small changes to `checkvalue()`:

```
# Other code: unchanged.

    def checkvalue(self):
        handvalue = 0
        for card in self.value:
            handvalue += card_val[card.grab_rank()]
        return handvalue

deck = Deck()
deck.shuffle()

hand = PlayerHand()
hand.hit()
hand.hit()
hand.hit()

print(hand)
print(hand.checkvalue())

# ['Jack of Hearts', '5 of Diamonds', '6 of Hearts']
# 21
```

A few small notes:

- The `PlayerHand.value` is a confusing variable name. Why not call it `PlayerHand.cards`? It's a list of Card instances, right?
- The `grab_rank()` and `grab_suit()` methods are unneeded. Just access `card.rank` and `card.suit` directly.

Comment: thanks, but I'm still having trouble implementing the changes you suggested in Python 2. More specifically the print function. Do you know how I can do this in Python 2?

Comment: @paulnsn Either remove the parentheses from the `print` calls, or add `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of the file.